# NSEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers randomly throws "TSMProcessRawKeyCode failed" exception

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone

Our Mac cocos2d app (http://deepworldgame.com) has been randomly throwing "TSMProcessRawKeyCode failed" exceptions for some time now, and I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this error or knows how to prevent it.

It always happens via the [NSEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers] call within ccKeysDown or ccKeysUp (it also happens for [NSEvent characters] without the modifiers). I don't think it's related to specific keys. Sometimes it only happens one time and the app continues to function afterward (if the exception is caught), but other times it essentially locks up keyboard input indefinitely and continues to cause exceptions with all future keypresses (again, when these exceptions are caught).

I've found little on the internets regarding this issue, unfortunately. One place I did find was in the Adium source code (https://bitbucket.org/adium/adium/src/6d1f9b903525/Source/AIExceptionController.m), which catches this exception with the comments:

```
//Ignore various known harmless or unavoidable exceptions (From the system or system hacks) 
...
// [TSMProcessRawKeyCode] May be raised by -[NSEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers]
```

It is indeed harmless when thrown once, but when the occasion happens that it continuously fires, it's a real problem - especially when you're in fullscreen mode and can't use cmd-F to escape!

So, if anyone has any thoughts or experience, I would be HIGHLY grateful. This is pretty much the one remaining superbug in our application, and I would love to squash it into dust.

Thanks!

Here is the typical stack trace (MacManager.m is our object which implements the cocos2d keyboard delegate protocol):

```
Crashed Thread:  7  CVDisplayLink

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[28871]: garbage collection is OFF
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'TSMProcessRawKeyCode failed (-192)'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x95b27d87 __raiseError + 231
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9315a149 objc_exception_throw + 155
2   CoreFoundation                      0x95a8f619 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 137
3   CoreFoundation                      0x95a8f589 +[NSException raise:format:] + 57
4   AppKit                              0x9ac01c1f _convertEventRefToString + 300
5   AppKit                              0x9ab23b5e -[NSEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers] + 880
6   Deepworld                           0x0001fd8a -[MacManager ccKeyDown:] + 65
7   CoreFoundation                      0x95a7d091 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 65
8   Deepworld                           0x0006bc95 -[CCEventDispatcher keyDown:] + 80
9   CoreFoundation                      0x95a7d091 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 65
10  Deepworld                           0x0006c014 -[CCEventDispatcher dispatchQueuedEvents] + 143
11  Deepworld                           0x0006a9a4 -[CCDirectorDisplayLink getFrameForTime:] + 155
12  Deepworld                           0x0006aaf1 MyDisplayLinkCallback + 40
13  CoreVideo                           0x9b44a5e1 _ZN13CVDisplayLink9performIOEP11CVTimeStamp + 489
14  CoreVideo                           0x9b4494e4 _ZN13CVDisplayLink11runIOThreadEv + 876
15  CoreVideo                           0x9b449161 _ZL13startIOThreadPv + 160
16  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x968a4ed9 _pthread_start + 335
17  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x968a86de thread_start + 34
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think sending events in general is thread-safe, not to mention from a thread that has been created not within +[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:] (a thread created using the Objective-C run-time has __NSThread__main__ in the backtrace).

I guess your app is the Deepworld binary part - when dispatching events, try using -[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:waitUntilDone:] instead, dispatching the events on the main thread.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case... I forgot to mention that we switched to using the main thread a couple of weeks ago and haven't encountered this since. Strangely, it's an option in Cocos2D to use the CVDisplayLink thread, a custom thread, or the main thread for execution... seems like the main thread is really the only option you'd want! (Unless you like random event errors...)